# to_csv() slows down after Pandas Version Update?

Tags: python, pandas

We upgraded our pandas from version 0.21.1 to 0.24.1

In 0.21.1- to_csv() wrote 64 million records with 200 columns in about 1.5 hours into a .csv file

`df.to_csv(filename, index=False)`

I made a software update and the very same line of code writes out forever.

Is there a better approach I can fall back to which could be much faster?

Comment: Are you restricted to just using .CSV? Could you trying `.to_json()` or `.to_pickle()`?

Comment: instead of pandas I preferred to use pyspark

Comment: I recall having a similar issue in the past, perhaps after `0.23`. I think the issue is with the `chunksize`. Try manually setting it to some enormous number of rows like `chunksize=1000000`. You clearly have the memory, so this should make it faster.

Comment: @JayKakadiya  I am restricted to a single node, but spark is installed and available. 
Should I convert my pandas dataframe to a spark dataframe ?

Comment: @SavageHenry has to be .csv()

Comment: _writes out forever_ Do you have any actual, well-constructed benchmarks?

Comment: @ALollz your approach of adding chucksize worked. Now I get back previous speeds. However I will explore more to adopt a better methodology. Appreciate all the replies. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In version `0.21.x` the definition was

```
DataFrame.to_csv(
path_or_buf=None, sep=', ', na_rep='', float_format=None, columns=None,
header=True, index=True, index_label=None, mode='w', encoding=None, 
compression=None, quoting=None, quotechar='"', line_terminator='\n', 
chunksize=None, tupleize_cols=None, date_format=None, doublequote=True, 
escapechar=None, decimal='.')
```

and in `0.24.x` the definition was

```
DataFrame.to_csv(
path_or_buf=None, sep=', ', na_rep='', float_format=None, columns=None, 
header=True, index=True, index_label=None, mode='w', encoding=None, 
compression='infer', quoting=None, quotechar='"', line_terminator=None, # Check these options
chunksize=None, tupleize_cols=None, date_format=None, 
doublequote=True, escapechar=None, decimal='.')
```

Only some parameters have changed. You might wanna look at them and check whether the function behaves as same as before.

Additionally try using `to_hdf` for writing large files

```
df.to_hdf('file.h5', key='some_key', mode='w')
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do it with `gzip` compression to make the process faster, also with `read_csv`, you can read the zipped CSV faster.

```
df.to_csv('your_file.csv.gz', compression='gzip')
```

Comment: Appreciate it, that did not help much. I am digging more

Comment: Writing with `gzip` compression is significantly slower.